# C Weird compiler behavior

Tags: c, compiler-construction, mingw

I am having some rather odd behavior with the MingW compiler for C.
I have a function, called getNextWord, shown here:

```
void getNextWord(FILE * pFile)
{
    char * w = (char *)malloc(MAX_WORD_SIZE * sizeof(char *));
    char * q = w;
    char c;
    while(c != ' ')
    {
        c = fgetc(pFile);
        if(c != ' ')
        {
            *(w++) = c;
        }
    }
    *(w++) = '\0';
    printf("%s\n",q);
    free(w);
}
```

For some reason, when I try to call this function twice in a row to print two words, it does not work.  Weirdly enough however, if I put anything at all between the function calls, including printf, or fseek, then the function works as you would expect it.

This works:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE * pFile = fopen("doc.txt", "r");
    getNextWord(pFile);
    printf("a");
    getNextWord(pFile);
    fclose(pFile);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

This does not work:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE * pFile = fopen("doc.txt", "r");
    getNextWord(pFile);
    getNextWord(pFile);
    fclose(pFile);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this is occurring?

EDIT:
Thanks for the help, this is the fixed function:

```
void getNextWord(FILE * pFile)
{
    char * w = (char *)malloc(MAX_WORD_SIZE * sizeof(char));
    char * q = w;
    char c;
    do
    {
        c = fgetc(pFile);
        if(c != ' ')
        {
            *(w++) = c;
        }
    } while(c != ' ');
    *(w++) = '\0';
    printf("%s\n",q);
    free(q);
}
```

Sorry for all the errors there was in the original post, I'm new to C.

Comment: may be off-topic, but `char * w = (char *)malloc(MAX_WORD_SIZE * sizeof(char *));` is a bit wrong - you need `sizeof( char )` not `sizeof( char* )`.

Comment: I just noticed that you have never "accepted" an answer so far. Please have a look at ["How does accepting an answer work?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Instead of putting the solution into your question, you should accept one of the answers. You can also post your own answer and accept it. "Accepting" an answer (by clicking on the check mark) marks the problem as solved (and gives some reputation points to you and to the author of the answer). - Please review your questions and check if you can accept answers.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you consider [*accepting*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) a useful answer now and then? Your history shows you have not done so for 16 questions, which suggests you are not aware of that option.

Answer (score 2):

The local variable `char c;` in `getNextWord()` is not initialized, therefore
the initial test in

```
while(c != ' ')
```

is undefined behaviour. You should initialize e.g. as

```
char c = 0;
```

Comment: That's rather odd it worked at all then.  Why would it work if only called once, but not twice?

Comment: Ah -- chances are pretty high the *last* value of `c` (which will usually be `' '`) is still on the stack, in the same position. Calling another function in between trashes the stack.

Answer (score 2):

You're freeing the wrong pointer, leading to undefined behavior.

You need to `free(q)`, not `w`, since `w` no longer points to what `malloc` returned.